# Initialize constexpr array with template functions

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, constexpr, stdarray

I am trying to create a `constexpr std::array` with precompiled handler functions for my emulator. The code below works just fine for smaller numbers like `0x250`, but everything above causes a 'C1026 parser overflow, program too complex' when used with the recent version of MSVC.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
using Executor = void(*)(T);

using IntExecutor = Executor<int>;

template<int arg>
void func(int value)
{
    std::cout << (arg * value) << std::endl;
}

// Static for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/173570/160845

template<typename T, T Begin, class Func, T ...Is>
constexpr void static_for_impl(Func&& f, std::integer_sequence<T, Is...>)
{
    (f(std::integral_constant<T, Begin + Is>{ }), ...);
}

template<typename T, T Begin, T End, class Func>
constexpr void static_for(Func&& f)
{
    static_for_impl<T, Begin>(std::forward<Func>(f), std::make_integer_sequence<T, End - Begin>{ });
}

template<int N>
constexpr std::array<IntExecutor, N> makeLut()
{
    std::array<IntExecutor, N> lut = { };
    static_for<size_t, 0, N>([&](auto x) {
        lut[x] = func<x>;
    });
    return lut;
}

// 0x250 works just fine
// 0x300 causes a "C1026 parser overflow, program too complex" error
constexpr auto lut = makeLut<0x250>();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int instruction = 0xDEADBEEF;

    int instructionHash = instruction & 0x24F;

    lut[instructionHash](instruction);

    return 0;
}
```

I need an `std::array` with the size of `0x1000`. I can achieve that by using `4` smaller `static_for()` loops from `0` to `0x250`, but I feel like that's an ugly solution.

Does anybody know a proper way to fill an `constexpr std::array` with template functions?

Comment: A little bit offtopic, but to have 0x1000 size you will need not 4, but 7-8 arrays of size 0x250. Back on topic, did you tried any other compilers? PS: Are you sure you really need `constexpr` array? Because it seems that just `const`, initialized in runtime, should suffice.

Comment: @sklott Whoops, forgot I was working with hexadecimals. The code compiles just fine using g++. Yes, I need a constexpr because otherwise I wouldn't be able to store `func<x>` in my array (afaik).

Comment: Which version of C++ is this? In C++20 `array::fill` is `constexpr`, so you use it instead.

Comment: @RadosławCybulski Array fill uses one value for the whole array. I want the passed functions to be different based on the current loop index, hence `func<x>`.

Comment: Ok, i see now. It does compile with clang as well. Maybe change your `static_for` implementation to use tree structure? Recursively split range in half and execute left, then right, until range is of size one, where you execute the function itself?

Comment: @RadosławCybulski I just feel like I should switch the compiler to clang. It seems like Visual Studio 2019 support it out of the box.

Comment: On a side note: in MSVC2017 one can use a regular for-loop in a constexpr function, makes code much easer to understand

Comment: Oh, and compilers usually have switches on the depth of templates and constexpr, maybe you just reached some limit that can be increased

Comment: @JVApen when using a regular for-loop I get the errors 'mismatch in format parameter list' and '=: unable to resolve function overflow'. I had to use some of the switched when compiling with g++. MSVC also has some of these, like `/constexpr:depth`, but errors lies in a parser stack overflow and I couldn't find one for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the solution based over `std::make_index_sequence`/`std::index_sequence` ?

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr std::array<IntExecutor, sizeof...(Is)> 
   makeLutHelper (std::index_sequence<Is...>)
 { return { func<int(Is)>... }; }

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr auto makeLut ()
 { return makeLutHelper(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}); }
```

I can't test it with MSVC but, in my Linux platform, g++ and clang++ compile also (with long, long time)

```
constexpr auto lut = makeLut<0x10000u>();
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you. I really have to dive deeper into template programming.

Comment: @jsmolka - I suppose it's because, this way, you avoid recursion. As far I know, compilers usually have configurable but strict limits to number of template recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the code max66 posted a little to allow constexpr array creation using a custom lamdba function. I am just pasting it here in case anybody needs it.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
using Executor = void(*)(T);

using IntExecutor = Executor<int>;

template<int arg>
void exec(int value)
{
    std::cout << (arg * value) << std::endl;
}

template<int value>
constexpr IntExecutor emitExecutor()
{
    return exec<value>;
}

template<typename T, class Func, std::size_t ...Is>
constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> makeArrayImpl(Func&& func, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return { func(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{})... };
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N, class Func>
constexpr std::array<T, N> makeArray(Func&& func)
{
    return makeArrayImpl<T>(std::forward<Func>(func), std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

constexpr auto executors = makeArray<IntExecutor, 0x1000>([&](auto x) {
    return emitExecutor<static_cast<int>(x)>();
});

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (const auto& executor : executors)
    {
        executor(10);
    }
    return 0;
}
```